# Apache Calcite: Handle special characters in MongoDB collection names

Tags: mongodb, apache-calcite

Is there a way to execute SQL queries on MongoDB if the collection's name contains special characters such as `1a84375b-9bd0-4ec3-9f93-536ce380f813`? I encounter `org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.ParseException` when I execute my statement. Are there any escape characters?

Answer (score 1):

In Calcite SQL, you can quote identifiers (table names and column names). In the default dialect, you use double quotes. For example,

```
SELECT "a column"
FROM "a table with spaces in the name"
```

Also note that when if identifiers are quoted, Calcite retains their case (it does not convert to upper or lower case) and uses case-sensitive matching.

By the way, this is the same as Oracle and several other common SQL dialects.

Comment: That works fine for me. I changed the default dialect in SQL_SERVER. Now, i encounter org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Table '6a3c9c9a-a607-46ad-8fca-7308d82d58a4' not found when i try to run SELECT [6a3c9c9a-a607-46ad-8fca-7308d82d58a4].id,[6a3c9c9a-a607-46ad-8fca-7308d82d58a4].name FROM [6a3c9c9a-a607-46ad-8fca-7308d82d58a4] against the MongoDB database. I already tried it with sqlline and verified with !tables the exist of 6a3c9c9a-a607-46ad-8fca-7308d82d58a4 as table name.